# How to pull variable environment into deployment.yml?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I created a process from Jenkins that builds a dockerfile and then creates a chart for me through the helm. The problem is that the name of the image I'm pushing to the dockerhub then repository changes according to the Jenkins build number.

`deployment.yaml`

```
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
```

`values.yaml`:

```
image:
  repository: photop/micro_focus
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "%image_tag%"
```

`Jenkinsfile`:

```
    stage ('Deploy&Operate HM'){
        steps{
            script{
        bat 'minikube start'
        bat 'kubectl create deployment %BUILD_NUMBER% --image="%BUILD_NUMBER%":latest'
        bat 'helm install  test-%BUILD_NUMBER% ./micro --set image_tag=%BUILD_NUMBER%'
```

Output:

```
Failed to apply default image tag "photop/micro_focus:%image_tag%": couldn't parse image reference "photop/micro_focus:%image_tag%": invalid reference format
```

How to change the variable of the Jenkins build and don't  %image_tag%  :

```
photop/micro_focus:%image_tag%
```

Comment: In your `helm install` command you `--set image_tag`, but you probably need to `--set image.tag` instead (with a period and not an underscore between the two words).  Does that push in the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

You just create the deployment which automatically applies to your cluster since you did not specify the --dry-run=client param. Therefore i do not understand why you would use helm install, it feels ambigious in this way. But i could be wrong and don't understand this way doings this way.